# Facebook-sdk library isn't available to import in eclipse

Tags: android, facebook, import, adt

I've just downloaded a facebook-sdk 3.6.0 and trying to import it in my eclipse workspace but here i got a problem - a facebook library is disable to import

[image]

Ok. then I've tried to download facebook-sdk from here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk and got the same problem. is it a bug?

Comment: The only time this happens to me is when the project has already been imported, are you sure it's not in your workspace already?

Comment: @Kai Damn! I have so many projects in my workspace so I didn't see it.

Comment: @Kai Make your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time this happens to me is when the project has already been imported, make sure it's not in your workspace already ;)